# GIT: how to list all gitignore rules in a folder

Tags: git, gitignore

What I want to do is to list all `gitignore` rules inside a folder. Assume the following folder structure:

```
project/
project/folderA/
```

Now if I want some `gitignore` rules for my whole project, I'd put it in `project/.gitignore`, but I could also add some rules to `project/folderA/.gitignore`, which as I understand, would apply to `project/folderA` and its subfolders only.

Now assume I do have some rules in both `.gitignore` files, and I'm in `project/folderA`, how can I list all `gitignore` rules that apply here? I need to see all the union of the ones inherited from parent folders and the ones existing in the current folder.

You can use the following command:

```
git check-ignore *
```

which would list you everything directly under the current folder which is ignored, and if you add a `-v` option, it would also show you the rule which has caused it to be ignored.

What I need is not to give an example and see if it's ignored or not, I simply need to see all the rules applying to the current folder.

**EDIT**: Some suggest that the `.gitignore` file in the subfolder overrides the parent and only that file needs to be checked. I've tested with git version `2.13.3` and this is not how it works. If I have `patternA` in parent folder, it IS ignored in the subfolder even if I don't have that same pattern in the subfolder's `.gitignore` file.

**EDIT 2**: Consider the following working example:

```
[user@machine tmp]$ mkdir test
[user@machine tmp]$ cd test/
[user@machine test]$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/test/.git/
[user@machine test]$ echo "a">.gitignore
[user@machine test]$ mkdir p
[user@machine test]$ cd p
[user@machine p]$ echo "b">.gitignore
[user@machine p]$ echo "c">.gitignore
[user@machine p]$ touch a 
[user@machine p]$ touch b
[user@machine p]$ cd ..
[user@machine test]$ touch a
[user@machine test]$ touch b
[user@machine test]$ git add .
[user@machine test]$ git status
On branch master

Initial commit

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)

    new file:   .gitignore
    new file:   b
    new file:   p/.gitignore

[user@machine test]$ cd p
[user@machine p]$ git list-git-ignore-rules-applied-here <-- hypothetical
```

As you can see, the only rule in the parent folder is `a`, and the two rules in the `p` folder are `a` and `b`, hence niether of those created files being tracked after `git add .`. Now the last line of that example code is what I need, which should give me the output:

```
a
b
c
```

Comment: You mean you want rules that explicitly apply to the folder or *could* apply to the folder, assuming you put a matching file in there (ie. rules that doesn't care about folders) ?

Comment: Why do you need this? Which problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: I've cloned a repo, and not I want to add a folder with a bunch of data in it. I need to know if there is any pattern resembeling `data` in my `gitignore` rules, that I can use and name my data folder as such. I also don't want to change any `.gitignore` files if I don't have to.

Answer (score -3):

As the [manual](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) states:

> "Patterns in the higher level files (up to the toplevel of the work
>   tree) being overridden by those in lower level files down to the
>   directory containing the file."

So only one `.gitignore` file is applied on your subdirectory, so for the rules applied you would only need to read out a single file.

Comment: I know that's what the manual says. But it's vague, and it doesn't work as you suggest.

Comment: If you add new lines to a .gitignore in a subfolder, the lines of the parent folder are still applied since git will continue to track any files that are already being tracked. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore?rq=1

Comment: The files being tracked by git have nothing to do with the lines being applied as the rules, and even if that made sense, your answer is still wrong.